# Tricentis Tosca 11.0 - How to install HOST Engine

Tags: automation, mainframe, tosca

I have a Mainframe/HOST Application to automate using Tosca 11.0, I am unable to scan/steer elements in mainframe screen.

Solution found in Tricentis Support -

---

The Tosca Host Engine is installed by default as part of a complete Tricentis Tosca installation.

All information regarding software versions and hardware requirements for the engine can be found in the "System Requirements for Tricentis Tosca".

The file PCSHLL32.DLL needs to exist in the system and the operating system needs to know the path to this file (with the system variable PATH).

The 3270 terminal emulation needs to be initialized correctly, so that the connection to the HOST system to be tested can be established. Additional information is available from your system administrator.

---

I couldn't locate PCSHLL32.DLL in my PC.

Has anyone faced same issue? can someone help where to get PCSHLL32.DLL and get HOST engine working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a while.  I kept trying to figure out how to install the Host module because I couldn't find that PCSHLL32.DLL on my system...

Turns out HOST was already there...  I just had to get Tosca Commander configured to find my terminal app (I'm using QWS3720 from Jolly Giant).

Try this - Go into Tosca Settings, and go to Settings > Special Engines > HostEngine> Emulation Environment and check the following settings:

1) Emulation Title: this should be the window title of your terminal emulator.  * works as a wildcard.  Since QWS3270 changes it's window name to match it's session, we just use * in this field.

2) Emulation Type: try to find your terminal emulator's maker listed here...  Mine is set to Jolly Giant.

3) Session ID: this is the important one.  This is the HLLAPI ID of the term window, basically the handle that automation needs to know to "see into" the terminal window.  it seems to typically be set to "A"  (same as with QuickTest Pro/UFT).

Once these settings are correct, then TRY to scan your terminal window.  Launch your terminal emulator first, CONNECT with it (to start up the HLLAPI), then run Tosca's scanner - just don't expect it to scan like web pages, it will use the older scanner.  Select Scan Application > Other...  and it will start the older "Tosca Wizard".  Click Scan, then point to your Terminal emulator.  If you see the little box showing "Recognized Wizard >HOSTEngine

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm using Tosca 11.0, In Emulation Type, I can only see below list 
PersonalCommunications
HostExplorer
InfoConnect
Rumba
Reflection and
User defined type

Emulator we are using is IntelliTerm, I selected all options, still having same issue.